# Turning a IEnumerable into a ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this IEnumerable

```
public static IEnumerable<Shipments> Shipments
{
    get
    {
        var hash = new HashSet<Routes>(new ShipmentsComparer()); // rename ShipmentsComparer cause it is actually RoutesComparer             
        foreach (var item in Loads)
        {
            if (item.ShipTo.Contains(" "))
            {
                foreach (var item2 in Routes.Where(d => d.DockCode == item.ShipTo.Substring(0, item.ShipTo.IndexOf(" ")) && d.CarrierDeparture.TimeOfDay == item.ShipTime.TimeOfDay))
                {
                    if (hash.Add(item2))
                    { 

                        yield return new Shipments { Arrival = item2.CarrierArrival, Departure = item2.CarrierDeparture, Issuer = item.Customer, Destination = item.ShipTo, LoadType = item.LoadType };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to add

```
yield return new Shipments { Arrival = item2.CarrierArrival, Departure = item2.CarrierDeparture, Issuer = item.Customer, Destination = item.ShipTo, LoadType = item.LoadType };
```

this into a `ObservableCollection`

At the moment I am using this IEnumerable to populate a `DataGrid` I am unable to keep using it this way as when the datagrid refreshes it removes the sorting that the user has selected.

EDIT:

**Class Shipments**

```
public class Shipments : BaseClass
    {
        private DateTime _Arrival;
        public DateTime Arrival
        {
            get { return _Arrival; }
            set { _Arrival = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Arrival)); }
        }

        private DateTime _Departure;
        public DateTime Departure
        {
            get { return _Departure; }
            set { _Departure = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Departure)); }
        }

        private string _Issuer;
        public string Issuer
        {
            get { return _Issuer; }
            set { _Issuer = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Issuer)); }
        }

        private string _Destination;
        public string Destination
        {
            get { return _Destination; }
            set { _Destination = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Destination)); }
        }

        private string _LoadType;
        public string LoadType
        {

            get
            {
                _LoadType = (Departure - Arrival).ToString();
                if (_LoadType == "00:30:00")
                {
                    _LoadType = "Drop Hook";
                }
                else
                {
                    _LoadType = "Live Load";
                }
                return _LoadType.ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                _LoadType = value;
            }
        }
```

**Comparer**

```
class ShipmentsComparer : IEqualityComparer<Routes>
    {
        public bool Equals(Routes route1, Routes route2) =>
            route1.DockCode == route2.DockCode && route1.CarrierArrival.Date == route2.CarrierArrival.Date &&
            route1.CarrierArrival.Hour == route2.CarrierArrival.Hour && route1.CarrierArrival.Minute == route2.CarrierArrival.Minute;


        public int GetHashCode(Routes obj) =>
        obj.DockCode.GetHashCode() ^ (obj.CarrierArrival.GetHashCode() * 13);
    }
```

The routes are added from a PDF file into a `ObservableCollection` Loads are added from a SQL statement into their own `ObservableCollection`

```
public static ObservableCollection<Routes> Routes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Routes>();

public static ObservableCollection<Loads> Loads { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Loads>();
```

Currently I use the `IEnumerable` Above

I would like it to be a `ObservableCollection` instead of a `IEnumerable` for easy refreshing of the `DataGrid` and keep items filtered.

Comment: Why? You can bind any multi-value control to `IEnumerable`. To update it, you only need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the collection/enumerable property itself. `ObservableColledtion` is needed only if you want to respond to individual add/remove events by updating only the item that changed. In this case though, you don't know whether there are any new or missing items. You'd need to re-iterate the `IEnumerable` in response to `Loads` and `Routes` changes.

Comment: Unrelated, but you're calculating `item.ShipTo.Substring(0, item.ShipTo.IndexOf(" "))` for each element in `Routes`, which is very wasteful

Comment: It seems you need to raise `PropertyChanged` for `Shipments` each time `Loads` and `Routes` change

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. It's true that if something that the getter depends on changes, you need to explicitly raise the `PropertyChanged` event for that property. But it's also just as true that for data binding purposes, this sort of approach is really poor. You seem to be implementing the getter simply to support filtering features, which is _much_ better handled by using `CollectionViewSource`. I'm afraid that from the question you posted, it's not really that clear what kind of advice you actually need.

Comment: Show the implementation of the Loads collection.
Maybe you need to make it an ObservableCollection?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes when I use the `RaisePropertyChanged` it basically refreshs the datagrid which removes the sorting the user has. I have it on a tick event to update. It's a shipments screen that when one of the shipments are shipped out that one gets removed. The `IEnumerable` is a result of matching data from 2 different `ObservableCollections` and using a `Comparer`

Comment: @EldHasp the Loads is an `ObservableCollection`

Comment: `public static ObservableCollection<Loads> Loads { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Loads>();`

Comment: @SmackYouIn2.3 so your *real* question is why sorting was lost, now how to create an ObservableCollection

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I suppose so. I asked a good friend of mine before I came here and he said this `"Yes it does refresh the whole table
If you don't want it go with ObservableCollection and add remove items accordingly."`
Which is why I made it with this title

Comment: But in this case you *have* to execute the iterator all over again. If you wanted to avoid this you'd have to calculate whether to add something to the ObservableCollection each time you modified `Loads` or `Routes`. You can create an `ObservableCollection` from that iterator easily by using the `ObservableCollection(Enumerable<T>)` constructor

Comment: Your goal: Preserve the state of the DataGrid when the original data changes.
To do this, you will have to completely revise the approach to solving the problem.
According to your code, I cannot understand the whole of your task, but in general, the Solution should contain, instead of IEnumerable <Shipments>, a listener for changes in the Loads collection.
And when it changes, change the ObservableCollection <Shipments> accordingly.

Comment: @EldHasp The IEnumerable is a result of matching data from 2 different ObservableCollections and using a Comparer.  I couldn't figure out how to match data between 2 `ObservableCollection` and add into a new one the results.

Comment: I can't understand from your code either.
If you can give a simple example of collections with data and the desired result.
The example is as simple as possible, but so that its solution is useful to you.

Comment: @EldHasp here is the question where I got help doing it, maybe it explains it better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412876/combining-matching-values-in-2-observablecollections-into-a-3rd-wpf/62427899#62427899

Comment: The task is solved in different ways depending on what properties Person has.
If ReadOnly - the solution will be easier.
It is also very important for what event the new filtering should take place.
If this is some kind of external event or method, then it can also be implemented much easier.

When do you have the datagrid refreshes happening?

Comment: @EldHasp I have edited the question to show you exactly how I am doing the process currently.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the edits you made to the topic question.
But I still do not understand many details of the question, so I cannot offer an implementation that is completely suitable for the answer:
Loads what type are the elements?
What is considered a change to an existing Shipments and what is a new Shipments instance?

The very unfortunate name of the Shipments collection property is the same as the item type name of this collection.

Here is an option, to the best of my understanding of your task.
But I cannot guarantee that it will suit you completely.

**ShipmentsComparer**

```
public class ShipmentsComparer : IEqualityComparer<Shipments>
{
    public bool Equals(Shipments left, Shipments right)
    {
        if (left == null) return right == null;

        return left.Arrival == right.Arrival &&
               left.Departure == right.Departure &&
               left.Issuer == right.Issuer &&
               left.Destination == right.Destination &&
               left.LoadType == right.LoadType;

    }

    public int GetHashCode(Shipments shipments)
    {
        int hashCode = 376624599;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + shipments.Arrival.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + shipments.Departure.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(shipments.Issuer);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(shipments.Destination);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(shipments.LoadType);
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

**RoutesComparer**

```
public class RoutesComparer : IEqualityComparer<Routes>
{
    public bool Equals(Routes route1, Routes route2) =>
        route1.DockCode == route2.DockCode && route1.CarrierArrival.Date == route2.CarrierArrival.Date &&
        route1.CarrierArrival.Hour == route2.CarrierArrival.Hour && route1.CarrierArrival.Minute == route2.CarrierArrival.Minute;


    public int GetHashCode(Routes obj) =>
    obj.DockCode.GetHashCode() ^ (obj.CarrierArrival.GetHashCode() * 13);
}

public class Routes
{
    public object DockCode { get; internal set; }
    public DateTime CarrierArrival { get; internal set; }
}
```

**Filtered**

```
    public ObservableCollection<Routes> Loads { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Routes>();

    public ObservableCollection<Routes> Routes { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Routes>();

    public ObservableCollection<Shipments> ShipmentsColl { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Shipments>();

    public void RenderRoutes()
    {
        var hashRoutes = new HashSet<Routes>(new RoutesComparer());
        HashSet<Shipments> hashShipments = new HashSet<Shipments>(new ShipmentsComparer());
        foreach (var item in Loads)
        {
            if (item.ShipTo.Contains(" "))
            {
                foreach (var item2 in Routes.Where(d => d.DockCode == item.ShipTo.Substring(0, item.ShipTo.IndexOf(" ")) && d.CarrierDeparture.TimeOfDay == item.ShipTime.TimeOfDay))
                {
                    if (hashRoutes.Add(item2))
                    {
                        // Forming a collection of results
                        hashShipments.Add( new Shipments { Arrival = item2.CarrierArrival, Departure = item2.CarrierDeparture, Issuer = item.Customer, Destination = item.ShipTo, LoadType = item.LoadType });
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        // We bring in line the public collection of the resulting collection of results.
        for (int i = ShipmentsColl.Count-1; i >=0; i--)
        {
            if (hashShipments.Contains(ShipmentsColl[i]))
                hashShipments.Remove(ShipmentsColl[i]);
            else
                ShipmentsColl.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        // Add missing results.
        foreach (Shipments shipments in hashShipments)
        {
            ShipmentsColl.Add(shipments);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. A couple things. The loads change by if the shipment has went out for the day if it has then it lowers how many items. It cross references a PDF file so I can get arrival time and match it up to show on the datagrid correctly. When I use your answer I am not getting anything in my view on my datagrid using ShipmentsColl. Do I need to trigger RenderRoutes in someway?

Comment: Yes.
When initializing or changing the original data, you need to call the method **RenderRoutes**.

Comment: You are using a static method.
But RenderRoutes is the usual method.
And all collections are usual (instance members), not static.
Unfortunately, the code you showed is not enough for me to understand how it all works.
And so I cannot give you a detailed and precise answer.
For understanding, lay out the complete code with the implementation of Loads, Routes, and methods that fill these collections.

Comment: is there a place we can chat?

Comment: Telegram @EldHasp  
But I warn you right away, my English (especially spoken) is very bad.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation for a simple example from the topic [Combining matching values in 2 observablecollections into a 3rd [WPF]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412876/combining-matching-values-in-2-observablecollections-into-a-3rd-wpf/62427899#62427899)

**Class Person**

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Person);
    }

    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        return other != null &&
               FirstName == other.FirstName &&
               LastName == other.LastName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = 1938039292;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(FirstName);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(LastName);
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

**Filtered**

```
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People1 { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {
            new Person("Donald", "Duck"),
            new Person("Daisy", "Duck"),
            new Person("Jack", "Daniels")
        };

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People2 { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {
            new Person("Donald", "Duck"),
            new Person("Daisy", "Duck"),
            new Person("Jim", "Beam")
        };

    public ObservableCollection<Person> PeopleInBothCollections { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public void RenderPeople()
    {
        List<Person> people = People1.Where(prs => People2.Contains(prs))
            .ToList();


        for (int i = PeopleInBothCollections.Count-1; i >=0 ; i--)
        {
            if (!people.Contains(PeopleInBothCollections[i]))
                PeopleInBothCollections.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        foreach (Person person in people)
        {
            if (!PeopleInBothCollections.Contains(person))
                PeopleInBothCollections.Add(person);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As an aside, your `GetHashCode` implementation can just be: `int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(FirstName, LastName);` (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode.combine?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Comment: I didn’t stress this because I don’t know how SmackYouIn2.3 implements the collection item class.
In my example, the default implementation from Visual Studio is "Quick Solutions".

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, on a blank line inside the class body, select "Quick Solutions" or "Quick Actions".
They have an item "Create Equals and GetHashCode".
But this is only one of the implementation variants.
You can create a comparator outside the class, or a compare-by-value function, or use a HashSet, and more.

Comment: The value "**int hashCode = 1938039292**" itself is a random literal chosen by Visual Studio.
You can replace the value with any other.